# I've made an anagram function in python, I cannot figure out how to get the output to look like this: "Key": word1, word2, word3 etc

Tags: python

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as read:
    line = read.readlines()

key_list = []

def make_anagram_dict(line):
    word_list = {}

    for word in line:
        word = word.lower()
        key = ''.join(sorted(word))
        if key in word_list and len(word) > 5:
            word_list[key].append(word)
            key_list.append(key)
        else:
            word_list[key] = [word]

    return word_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_list = make_anagram_dict(line)

    for words in word_list.values():
        if len(words) > 1:
            print('Words: {}'.format(', '.join(words)))
```

I.e I need it to look like this:

```
Key: 
aeehrtw

Words: 
weather
, whereat
, wreathe
```

I also have a problem where words in the .txt file are duplicated but one word starts with a capital, i.e Zipper and zipper. How can I have it so that it only uses one of the words?

Comment: and what does it currently look like?

Comment: Words: weather
, whereat
, wreathe

Comment: You just want to insert a newline ? `print('Words: {}'.format('\n, '.join(words)))` ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the `.txt` file?

Comment: Sure, the words.txt fle is just a list of words A-Z:
abacate
abacay
abacinate
abacination
abaciscus
abacist
aback
abactinal
abactinally
abaction
abactor
abaculus
abacus
Abadite

Comment: I'm not sure how to remove duplicate words from dictionary

Comment: Use a `set` instead of a list...

Comment: How could I use a set instead? Would it be possible to show how I could edit the code I have? Ty

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact same output, you can try :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_list = make_anagram_dict(line)

    for key, words in word_list.items():
        if len(words) > 1:
            print('Key:')
            print(key)
            print()
            print('Words:')
            print('\n, '.join(words))
```

Comment: Thanks Benbb96, how could I make sure that no duplicates come through? The words.txt has duplicates (Zipper and zipper),

Comment: You shouldn't have this problem since you're using lower case for your key : `word = word.lower()`

Comment: What does the "if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_list = make_anagram_dict(line)" part mean?

Comment: I didn't change this part, I reused your own code. It means you get the word list from your function `make_anagram_dict` defined in your question.